# Django queryset multiple aggregation

Tags: django, django-queryset

You would like to extract call statistics about reiteration during a period.

Example :

```
class Call(models.Model):
    when_start = models.DateTimeField()
    when_end = models.DateTimeField()
    caller = models.CharField()
    dnis = models.CharField()
```

I should get this :

```
result = {4: 1, 3: 3, 2: 4, 1: 1}
```

Detail :

- 4: 1  => 1 person called 4 times
- 3: 3  => 3 persons called 3 times
- 2: 4  => 4 persons called 2 times
- 1: 1  => 1 person called 1 times

I tried with this queryset but I obtain a result by caller :

```
Call.objects.filter(when_start__range=(dt_start, dt_end)).values('caller').annotate(caller_count=Count('caller')).order_by('-caller_count')

[{'caller_count': 4, 'caller': u'Mr X'},
{'caller_count': 3, 'caller': u'Mr Y'}, 
{'caller_count': 3, 'caller': u'Mr T'},
{'caller_count': 3, 'caller': u'Mr E'},
{'caller_count': 2, 'caller': u'Mr O'},
{'caller_count': 2, 'caller': u'Mr M'},
{'caller_count': 2, 'caller': u'Mr P'},
{'caller_count': 2, 'caller': u'Mr B'},
{'caller_count': 1, 'caller': u'Mr N'}]
```

So I must add this code to obtain result :

```
result = {}

for data in calls:
    if data['caller_count'] not in result:
        result[data['caller_count']] = 1
    else:
        result[data['caller_count']] += 1
```

Is it possible to get this result directly with only one queryset ?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, but you could use `defaultdict(int)` to simplify your for loop. It's not going to be that bad because ideally the number of the aggregated result is much less than the original object count.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do next:

```
Call.objects.filter(when_start__range=(dt_start, dt_end))
            .values('caller').annotate(caller_count=Count('caller'))
            .order_by('-caller_count').annotate(Count('caller_count'))
```

Comment: Yes : `FieldError: Cannot compute Count('caller_count'): 'caller_count' is an aggregate`